# Trying to generate a Tile labyrinth in Unity

Tags: unity, c#, algorithm, maze

So I have a generator code that renderes a TileMap on the scene, but It keeps creating a sollid block of walls
[image][image: A block]

Where I want it to have empty cells(**This is not the  final algorythm(Recursive Backtracker)**, just the begining where we fill the maze), I'm following this tutorial,trying to addjust it to the Tilemap (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ya1HyptE5uc&t=870s), here is my code for the renderer

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Tilemaps;

public class MazeRenderer : MonoBehaviour {
    [SerializeField]
    [Range(1, 50)]
    private int width = 10; // width of the maze
    [SerializeField]
    [Range(1, 50)]
    private int height = 10; // height of the maze
    [SerializeField]
    private Tilemap floorMap; // Tilemap for the floor(without collider, render layer 0)
    [SerializeField]
    private Tilemap collidableMap; //  Tilemap for the walls(with the collider, render layer 1)
    [SerializeField]
    private TileBase floorTile = null; // base tile for the floor
    [SerializeField]
    private TileBase wallTile = null; // base tile for a wall
    [SerializeField]
    private Transform wallPrefab = null; // unused code for a regular wall prefab
    [SerializeField]
    private int size = 1;// offset for tile placement
    private void Start()
    {
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        var maze = MazeGenerator.Generate(width, height);// creating a maze with width and height
        Draw(maze); // rendering the maze with the Draw() method
    }
    private void Draw(Node[,] maze)// Draw method, takes in an 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) // simple floor generation 
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < height; j++)
            {
                var position = new Vector3Int(-i, -j, 0); // floor generation from the negative position
                floorMap.SetTile(position, floorTile); //setting floor tiles
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < width; i++) //maze generation
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < height; j++)
            {
                var  cell = maze[i,j]; //creates connections between cells
                var position = collidableMap.WorldToCell(new Vector3(-width + i, -height + j, 0));//sets  cells positions
                if(cell.TopWall) //sets top tile for the cell
                {
                    position = collidableMap.WorldToCell(position + new Vector3Int(0, size, 0));
                    collidableMap.SetTile(position, wallTile);
                }
                if (cell.LeftWall) // sets left tile for the cell
                {
                    position = position  + new Vector3Int(-size, 0, 0);
                    collidableMap.SetTile(position, wallTile);
                }
                if (i == width - 1) // checks if we reached the right side of the maze
                {
                    if (cell.RightWall) //generates right wall
                    {
                        position = position + new Vector3Int(size, 0, 0);
                        collidableMap.SetTile(position, wallTile);
                    }
                }

                if (j == 0) // checkes if we reached bottom
                {
                    if (cell.BottomWall) // generates bottom wall
                    {
                        position = position + new Vector3Int(0, -size, 0);
                        collidableMap.SetTile(position, wallTile);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

And for the generator:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public struct Node // setups up all possible wall placements + if the cell has been visited or not 
{
    public bool LeftWall;
    public bool RightWall;
    public bool TopWall;
    public bool BottomWall;
    public bool isVisited;
}
public struct Position // position of the neighbouring cell
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
}
public struct Neighbour // creates a full neighbour position with possible wall placements
{
    public Position position;
    public Node sharedNode;
}
public static class MazeGenerator{
    public static Node[,] Generate(int width, int height)//generates possible wall  placements in a maze
    {
        Node initial = new Node(); //creating initial tile with all true possible wall placements
        initial.LeftWall = true;
        initial.RightWall = true;
        initial.TopWall = true;
        initial.BottomWall = true;
        Node[,] maze = new Node[width, height]; //creating an array of wall placements
        for(int i = 0; i < width; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < height; j++)
            {
                maze[i, j] = initial; // inputing initial wall placements into array
            }
        }
        return maze; //returning array
    }
    

}
```

picture of the objects in the scene[image]

MazeRenderer is the only object in the scene that has a script(MazeRenderer),

Answer (score 1):

It is a solid block of walls because you tell it to generate a solid block of walls.

```
if(cell.TopWall)  {
    position = collidableMap.WorldToCell(position + new Vector3Int(0, size, 0));
    collidableMap.SetTile(position, wallTile);
}
```

every single cells is having cell.TopWall true according to your MazeGenerator since you never change it. This should be always true, so your loop just places a tile everywhere.

As a side node, you want to generate your maze once and not in `Update()`